# protofile.proto: A file with this name is already in the pool

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, grpc, file-descriptor

Having the following structure:

```
- project1
  - project1.py
  - protofile_pb2.py
  - protofile_pb2_grpc.py
- project2
  - project2.py
  - protofile_pb2.py
  - protofile_pb2_grpc.py
```

project1.py:

```py
import protofile_pb2.py
...
```

project2.py:

```py
import protofile_pb2
import project1
...
```

When running project2.py, I get this error:

```
TypeError: Couldn't build proto file into descriptor pool!
Invalid proto descriptor for file "protofile.proto":
protofile.proto: A file with this name is already in the pool.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using different versions of your generated protofile.proto. Make sure to regenerate the protobuf files and it should work fine.

Answer (score 9):

According to [this comment](https://github.com/google/protobuf/issues/3002#issuecomment-314179893), it worked for me:

```
pip uninstall protobuf
pip install --no-binary protobuf protobuf
```

Answer (score 5):

I faced similar issue while deploying google cloud functions in Python. My cloud function was using different versions of .proto files in my module (which was again a private module which I wanted to install using requirements.txt). The solution is to use pure python implementation instead of using binary implementation of protobuf. To solve this in cloud functions or in cloud build you can set cloud functions env variables to use python implementation of protocol buffers.

In your gcloud cloud function deploy command use following option:

```
<start of command> --set-env-vars=PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION='python' <your rest of the command>
```

or if you are in any other env/os simply do this

```
export PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION='python'
```

This solved my issue.

Comment: Thank you! Your workaround seems to make things faster too when using `sentencepiece_model_pb2`

Answer (score 0):

### For protobuf>=3.20.x

Install Protocol Buffers library for Python

```
pip install protobuf
set PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION=python
```

Clean the caches and `restart the kernel`

### Alternatives

Downgrade the protobuf package to 3.20.x or lower

```
pip install protobuf=3.11.3
```

> Search for any duplicate occurrences of the `sentencepiece_model.proto` file in your project. Make sure there is only one copy of the file present.